# I am trying fill the NA values in the Age column with the mean value of Ages based on Sex

Tags: r

```
impute.age <- function(age, sex){
  corrected.age <- age
  if(is.na(age) & sex == 1){
    corrected.age <- male.mean.age
  }else if(is.na(age) & sex == 0){
    corrected.age <- female.mean.age
  }else{
    return(corrected.age)
  }
}
```

I wrote this function, and this doesn't seem to be working. Is there any other ways where I can fill NA values in the Age column with the mean of value of Ages based on sexes (Male and Female)

Comment: Please show the structure of your actual data frame which contains both ages and genders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using R base**:

```r
ref_mean <- tapply(df$Age, df$Sex, mean, na.rm=T)
df[df$Sex=="Male" & is.na(df$Age), "Age"] <- ref_mean["Male"]
df[df$Sex=="Female" & is.na(df$Age), "Age"] <- ref_mean["Female"]
```

**Using [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html):**

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Age := nafill(Age, fill=mean(Age, na.rm=T)), by=Sex]
```

**Using [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/):**

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Sex) %>%
  mutate(ifelse(is.na(Age), mean(Age, na.rm=T), Age))
```

where `Age` and `Sex` are your Age and Sex columns. Also, you may need to replace `"Male"` and `"Female"` by `"1"` and `"0"`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

If you use indexing, you don't even need any `if`/`else`:

```
# example data
age <- sample(10:70, 50, replace = TRUE)
age[sample(length(age), 10)] <- NA_integer_
sex <- sample(c("M","F"),50, replace = TRUE)

# computing means
mean_M <- mean(age[sex == "M"], na.rm = TRUE)
mean_F <- mean(age[sex == "F"], na.rm = TRUE)

# replacing by the means
age[is.na(age) & sex == "M"] <- mean_M
age[is.na(age) & sex == "F"] <- mean_F
```